# Why are spiders spawning on my 2x2 platform?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The wiki says normal spiders need a 3x3x2 area to spawn, I was wondering how true this is?

I've noticed them spawn in areas 2x2x2? Any help is appreciated.

Source:  https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spider

UPDATE: Image of spiders spawning
http://postimg.org/image/67bo9lkh1/

Comment: Can you verify that it spawned in a 2x2x2 area? Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: Sure, im trying now. :)

Comment: I've added a screenshot link. I'm sure I'm just understanding it wrong.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? At the moment it looks like a statement of fact, which is difficult to answer.

Answer (score 10):

The 3x3x2 spawning requirement is referring to the *empty* space.  Spawning only requires a solid block *under* the spawn area.

> Light level of 7 or less, 3x3x2 space on solid blocks (**spawns only on top of the central block**). Top half of space may be occupied by transparent blocks (glass, etc.).

This means that the requirement is a 3x3x2 area of empty space with a solid block under the middle empty block.  With that in mind, it is easy to see numerous valid spawning locations in your screenshot.

Comment: Yes that clears it up, that's why they spawned on a 2x2 because they see the air block as valid empty space. Thanks

Comment: Spiders are, IIRC, 1.4 meters wide. So, when spawning in the center of block, they need 20cm of each surrounding block to be free - they may spawn on a block between two fences (this is an idea, not a fact).

Comment: @OrcJMR The 3x3x2 requirement prevents that, since the fences don't count as the necessary air blocks.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie While Spider page on the wiki states this 3x3x2, algorithm on Spawning page does not mention the requirement for Air blocks, only "non-opaque" and "must not be obstructed". Sooo I went ahead and did it: http://i.imgur.com/OCysloW.png **Spiders spawn next to fences.**

Comment: @OrcJMR Oh, that's interesting. The "must not be obstructed" is usually understood to mean that non-air, non-full-block blocks prevent spider spawning, and it's true of things like slabs, but apparently not fences. I know signs prevent spawning when they are on *every* block, but maybe replacing those fences with signs would still let spiders spawn...